# What were the average prices of diamonds in the late 1940s, in France specifically?

Tags: economy

I’m writing this little story in which the main character is a diamond dealer/scammer set in late 40s Paris. She sells diamonds to clients but they’re actually fake and stuff like that.  I need a price range on how expensive they were and what they would’ve cost in the currency of the time. Does anyone have any insight or websites they could link?

Comment: Diamond price goes up 2-3% a year, roughly. But the Rappaport index starts (AFAIR) in 1978. As you ask about France, there's a lot of information [here](https://www.diamants-infos.com/taille/evolution-prix-diamants.html) but it a *very* wide range because it depends on many parameters.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Might be better suited for Economics.SE

Answer (score -2):

Due to the war (where output was down) diamond prices were really starting to ramp up by the later forties, starting out at $50per carat in 1944 they'd doubled to $100per carat by 1949.

And that's USD, France would likely be higher due to high post-war demand and the need to import (so duties / taxes on top too).

De Beers opened their first office in Paris in 1947 to help meet rising demand for diamonds in France and continental Europe, De Beers will've held a major control on global diamond distribution at the time. Might be a nice tid-bit to include if it's in your time-frame.

A guide of $125-$150 per carat would not be outside the realm of believability for your setting due to this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Where do these numbers come from? Any reliable source regarding them?

Comment: Portions of this answer show a high probability (88.76%) that they are generated by an AI  bot and not resolved through research. AI generated answers are not factually reliable and not allowed on this site.